Why does drop_duplicates in_place = True not work in this case?
Sample data:
data = [[1, 'john@example.com'], [2, 'bob@example.com'], [3, 'john@example.com']]
person = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'email']).astype({'id':'int64', 'email':'object'})

Reproducible code:
(person.sort_values(by = ['email', 'id'], ascending = [True, True])
     .drop_duplicates(subset = 'email', keep = 'first', inplace = True))

I expected the code above to revise person so it looks like
   id             email
1   2   bob@example.com
0   1  john@example.com

But instead person still looks like its original form
   id             email
0   1  john@example.com
1   2   bob@example.com
2   3  john@example.com

If I break up the methods into two parts, then it works
person1 = person.sort_values(by = ['email', 'id'], ascending = [True, True])
person1.drop_duplicates(subset = 'email', keep = 'first', inplace = True)

In this case person1 looks like the desired format:
   id             email
1   2   bob@example.com
0   1  john@example.com

Why doesn't the first code remove duplicated email in-place?

Your first code is more or less equivalent to:
temporary = person.sort_values(by = ['email', 'id'], ascending = [True, True])
temporary.drop_duplicates(subset = 'email', keep = 'first', inplace = True)
del temporary

Thus, the temporary dataframe is modified and then discarded
If you want to chain commands, you should not use inplace=True, and assign the output to a variable:
out = (person.sort_values(by = ['email', 'id'], ascending = [True, True])
             .drop_duplicates(subset = 'email', keep = 'first')
      )

Output:
   id             email
1   2   bob@example.com
0   1  john@example.com

Or only use in place commands:
person.sort_values(by = ['email', 'id'], ascending = [True, True], inplace=True)
person.drop_duplicates(subset = 'email', keep = 'first', inplace=True)
print(person)

